# Geometry Nodes: Material's Total Area (Accumulate Field Total Unique)

Tags: geometry-nodes, spreadsheet

I want to get area spreadsheet of all materials on mesh, and since there is no domain "materials", i think the best method is place points at mean location of separated by materials mesh, First I thought about set position on mean location of separated by material's mesh and merge it, but i think it's pretty unoptimized method
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geometry Nodes:

[image: Geo Nodes 1]

Here it stores in faces the added area of faces of the same material. The average position is done by the same way, but the sum is divided by the total of faces with the same material.

[image: Attribute values 1]

You can generate points containing the area and material index for each material doing this:

[image: Geo Nodes 2]

[image: mesh with points]

[image: points with area and material index attributes]

**Edit: accurate center position (based on vertex position)**

[image: Geo Nodes 3]

[image: Material Selection Area Node Group]

[image: Set Position at Index Group Node]

With this method, for every material, you will need to add new row of nodes, set the material index and add a switch to get the value when the point index is equal to the material index selected.

[image: add new node row]

You will also need increase the point count to the new material count.

Comment: So, this is pretty good example for understanding the Accumulate filed node i guess